# Signal SIGSTOP received in the ARM Assembly in libc?

Tags: linux, assembly, arm

Trying to understand this ARM assembly . I get a SIGSTOP signal for this. Something is going wrong here.I ll try but need some help

```
afd0c750:   push {r4, r7}        
afd0c754:   mov r7, #252    ; 0xfc  // what is this I think that its calling the SWI and it need the r7 to have this value.  
afd0c758:   svc 0x00000000
afd0c75c:   pop {r4, r7}
afd0c760:   movs r0, r0
afd0c764:   bxpl lr 
afd0c768:   b 0xafd3896c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIGSTOP` is sent to process to suspend it - for later resumption - and is not an error condition - or directly generated by one.

The most likely scenario is that your process has received `SIGSTOP` whilst the thread is executing in the kernel - and most likely blocked there.   Your backtrace will show the `SVC` instruction as the last executed on the user-stack as this is a user-space to kernel transition.

It is not clear from your description how the `SIGSTOP` is manifested.  A likely candidate is `gdb` being the source of it.

The full backtrace would be very useful here.

Comment: Yes Thank you . YOu are right this is gdb debugging. I am doing android-ndk gdb debugging for the c/c++ code .Somewhere along the line , My code is stopping like this at epoll_wait which is a way for the kernel to wait for certain event. Thank you Marko and Masta79

Comment: To add to this, although I do not know why, the application that I am debugging is receiving SIGSTOPs nonstop (hoho!). To allow the application to keep running one can do 'handle SIGSTOP nostop noprint' at the gdb prompt (the noprint is useful because otherwise gdb stops the app to allow you to read one page at a time).